# How can I use callbacks between two AngularJS factories?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

In my AngularJS app I got two factories called "editInfo" and "pinVerify". What I'm trying to do is to have the editInfo factory call the pinVerify service with a callback function like this `pinVerify.sendPin(this.saveInfo)` and then save that method inside the pinVerify factory for when the user has inputted the pin and presses a button calling `pinVerify.pinEntered()`

The problem with this is that the callback-method will get copied into the pinVerify object and will be unable to reference properties in the editInfo factory.

So... naturally I tried using `$q.defer()` inside the pinVerify factory instead, and resolve it in `pinVerify.pinEntered()` when the user enters the pin sent out by SMS.

This works perfectly fine, and I can inside the editInfo factory do this instead of using callbacks:

```
pinVerify.sendPin().then(function() {
    this.saveInfo();
}
```

And the saveInfo method will detect if the pin was correct and hide the modal to enter it.  The problem arises when the pin *is not correct*.

The promise has already been resolved, so another click on the button calling `pinVerify.pinEntered` will do nothing basically.  I can not resolve it twice.

So now I'm kind of back where I started, and seriously considering heavy drinking while on the job...

Any suggestions for how I can accomplish this kind of relationship between two factories? Suggestions on good beers/vodkas works too I guess.

Comment: Hard to help without understanding how this modal works. and seeing more code.  Sounds like a case where `$q.all(promise1,promise2)` might help....or just throw away the cap on that bottle

Comment: $q.all won't help me since `pinVerify.pinEntered` can be called an infinite number of times and the actual verification of the entered pin is done in the other factory `editInfo`

Comment: Is this using angular-ui modal? ANd you close the modal prematurely before the validation?

Comment: No it's just a div with ng-show, it's not closed until editInfo's `this.saveInfo();` function has determined if the pin was correct or not. I'm now looking at using a closure method calling `self.saveInfo()` instead - to see if that might work. A $q promise seems less and less likely to work in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my first try before even going into the $q promise looked like this and didn't work - `pinVerify.sendPin(self.saveAddress);`

I just now solved it myself using a closure-method as the callback and then inside it calling the actual method using a previously declared `var self = this;` like this

```
pinVerify.sendPin(function() {
    self.saveAddress();
});
```